# how to compare two tables from mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to tables that I would like to compare.  Table1 has a list of all users table2 may or may not have all users listed.  I would like to echo the users that are not listed in table2.

I am tring to use array_diff. I can not get it to work, the result is always the very last user from table2

```html
<?
$array1 = array("a" => "'table1.$username'");
$array2 = array("b" => "'table2.$username'");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: something along the lines of `select * from table1 where username not in ( select username from table2 )` possibly?

Comment: RamRaider, that seamed to work, only it picks up all of them except the last user that is not in table 2.  any idea why that would be?  ty

Comment: RamRaider, I figured it out.  it is not picking it up because I had one other variable in my echoed tables that is not represented in the select.

Comment: good stuff - glad you sorted it

Comment: so this is what i ended up with -                                                             $sql_events = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM authorize WHERE username not in ( SELECT username FROM weekpicks WHERE whatweek='$totalnoOfWeek' ) ORDER BY 'username' asc ")

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea- if you are pulling to a front end from a structured DB then you can skip some php calcs and do the diff in MySQL using an anti join. Or if unfamiliar with anti join you can use the exist() function. It depends on what/where you are trying to achieve the diff of data.